# Dreamweaver jump between two commonly used areas of code for long files

Tags: dreamweaver

I dont know if this is possible, but if Im working on two areas of code in a long file, I have to note the line numbers and scroll between the two areas of code. Is there a way you can jump between two commonly used areas of code?

Perhaps setup a flag of some sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dreamweaver doesn't have a 'bookmark line" type of functionality. However, if you know the lines you're jumping between you can use CTRL+G (not sure of the matching one on Mac) or Edit -> Go To Line and that will bring up, a small UI that allows you to enter in the line number to jump to. I use this all the time.

Answer (score 0):

It's command + comma on the mac to bring up the Go to Line dialog box.